# MYSQL trigger to update another table?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a 'product' table which holds the unique id and the stock of products, I've created another 'statistics' table which has a foreign key to the product_id and values for incoming and outgoing.

The product stock is updated via an API and is either incremented/decremented by a value. On an update I'd like to increment either the incoming or outgoing values of the 'statistics' table but I'm having trouble with the syntax.

I'm thinking the trigger should happen after an update on the 'product' table and something like this occurs:

```
if new.product_stock < old.product_stock
    update statistics set outgoing += (the value) where statistics.product_id = product.product_id

else if new.product_stock > old.product_stock
    update statistics set incoming += (the value) where statistics.product_id = product.product_id
```

How would I go about creating a trigger like this, and do I have access to the value from the update or do I calculate it by taking the absolute of (new - old)?

I've tried just as a test something like this:

```
create trigger update_stats after update on product 
for each row
update statistics set incoming = 5 where statistics.product_id = product.product_id;
```

which doesn't do anything to the statistics table and also stops the update to the product table from happening.

Comment: 'I'm having trouble with the syntax.' - do you have an error message or can you not figure out how to do it?

Comment: No error message just struggling with how it works, I've updated the question to show I tried just setting a static value on an update which doesn't work

Comment: You should be referring to NEW.product_id in the trigger.

Comment: thank you that has put me on the right track!